# How can I compare datagridview cell of datagridview1 with another datagridview cell of datagridview2 in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

```
[if Name(cell data) for datagridview1] == Name(cell data) for datagridview2 background color should be in red color.
```

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming both Datagridviews remain in the same form, right?

Comment: Yes steve.. both Datagridviews are in the same form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be the method you're looking for.
there 'might' be a few syntax errors because I've written this out of my mind. But I hope I've helped you out further with this.

Don't forget to define the event in the datagridview1 itself too. (under datagridview1 > properties > events)

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
          string dgv1value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.Rowindex].Cells[e.Columnindex].Value.ToString();
          foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridview2.rows)
          {
               if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dgv1value)
               {
                    //Continue your code here
               }
          }
    }
```

If it didn't worked out yet, please tell me in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void CompareDataGridColumnForward(DataGridView dgv1, DataGridView dgv2)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = dgv1.RowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dgv2.RowCount - 1; j++)
                {
                    string dgv1value = dgv1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv2.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dgv1value)
                        {
                            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public static void CompareDataGridColumnReverse(DataGridView dgv1, DataGridView dgv2)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = dgv2.RowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dgv2.RowCount - 1; j++)
                {
                    string dgv2value = dgv2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv1.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == dgv2value)
                        {
                            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: On loading data for two datagridview CompareDataGridColumnReverse and CompareDataGridColumnForward are invoke